# SVN Merge from branch to trunk is not working as expected

Tags: svn, subversive, svn-merge

In order to do some refactoring I copied the trunk in a new branch. Refactoring included renaming `Java Source` to `src` and deleting `Web Content` folder. But after making desired changes in the branch and executing `svn merge` from the trunk the refactoring changes were not reflected. Though merging did pull in the code changes from the branch. Am I doing something wrong here?

Trunk structure:

[image: Trunk structure]

Branch structure:

[image: Branch structure]

Merged Trunk structure: (no changes reflected)

[image: Merged Trunk structure: (no changes reflected)]

Comment: Can you tell us the actual commands you used to create the branch, and to merge back into trunk?

Comment: @demoncodemonkey I did a svn copy from SVN Repository Exploring perspective and pasted in the new branch folder and made the changes. For the merge, I created a new workspace, pulled in the trunk and using "Team -> Merge" specified the branch url. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I was not able to identify the main cause of the problem but my Subversive plug-in was 6 years old and that could be a possible reason. The way I created branch was perfectly correct and to verify that I ended up installing **Subclipse** plug-in instead and using `Team -> Merge` everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Subclipse before, however [this guide](http://davisfiore.co.uk/?q=node/93) shows how to create a branch, and it seems pretty different to just copy/paste.

I'm guessing you created your branch incorrectly, and that's why you're having trouble merging.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow. I read somewhere that in svn everything is a "svn copy" and so copied the trunk..

Comment: Also, why did it pull the other code changes if the branch was corrupt in the first place?